# Full height of Toggle shows when Toggle is closed

Tags: javascript, php

I have a toggle that works perfectly, my problem is when the toggle is closed the the full height of the open toggle div still shows even when closed.

[image]

It is annoying as the whole point of me using a toggle was to make more room on the page. This is my first time creating a toggle so i am not quiet sure how to resolve this issue.

The content of my toggle is created via a string:

```
        echo("<button id='onclick' onclick='toggle_visibility(\"first_product$i\")'> " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </button>");

        echo("<div id='first_product'>");


        echo("<div id='first_product$i' class ='hidden'>");

        echo("<div id='red_head'>");
        echo("<p id='menu_title'  onclick='toggle_visibility(\"first_product$i\")'>  " . $_SESSION['Food_Cat_name'] . " </p>");
        echo("</div>");
```

Javascript

```
           //toggle and change bg colour
function toggle_visibility(tog) {
    var e = document.getElementById(tog); 
    if(e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") { 
        e.style.display = "none"; 
      
    } else { 
        e.style.display = "block"; 
       
        
    } 
}
```

I cannot seem to workout where i may have gone wrong.

```js
//toggle and change bg colour
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id); 
        if(e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") { 
            e.style.display = "none"; 
            text.innerHTML = "+"; 
        } else { 
            e.style.display = "block"; 
           text.innerHTML = "-";
            
        } 
    }
```

```css
div#first_product{
width: 50%;
margin-left: 320px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #f1f1f2 !important;
    
}

div#red_head{
background-color: #ed1c24;
height: 40px;
color: #fff;
padding-left: 15px;
line-height: 35px;
}

#onclick{
width: 50%;
height: 30px;
margin-left: 320px;
background-color: #f8f9f9;
border: 1px dashed #afafaf;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id='onclick' onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')">Toggle</button>

<div id="first_product">
    <div id="red_head">
        <p id="menu_title" class ="hidden" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')">  Add your first menu item</p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="menu">Menu Section</h3>

    <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               

        <label id="cat_label" name="cat_label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="cat_name" name="cat_name" value="">

        <label id="desc_label" name="desc_label">Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="cat_desc" name="cat_desc" value="">

        <input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod"  value=" + ADD">
```

It works perfectly in HTML. But it doesn't when using strings. I have made some changes to my javascript by the way, trying to resolve my problem

Comment: <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion">  http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

Comment: well, what display style do you see from the inspector? Any errors in the console? Do you have a demo page somewhere?

Comment: @Yezz know errors what do ever. I have used strings to echo the data into a form. so will html do to demo it. I am so merely using display none, a width and a bg colour

Comment: first_product$i renders an element id? As that is what you pass to the function and then use. Ok I will await the demo

Comment: yes htmnl is fine if it's exactly the same as the php render

Comment: @yezzz THE $i is a loop as the form i am using is a string

Comment: is the current code snippet your demo? As I see no issue, the toggle sets the product to display none and the demo body  then leaves 30px height. But you now have both toggle functions running, and there is an issue with text: not defined. Better edit one function out

Answer (score 0):

You create the html in a loop, and each product has a button. Do they all have the same ID? Which could mean trouble. Same with other elements. `echo("<div id='first_product'>");` If you have multiple of those, change it. Either use classes, or add the $i or something random to all those id's.

For the button text you need to target the button, not the product id.

Comment: sorry. my internet kept failing. That is just the HTML version the string version has the $i variable. I have tried that too it doesn't work. I may try a plugin to collapse toggle